# How to run a ZSH glob command recursively for sub-directories

Tags: shell-script, scripting, zsh

I have a ZSH glob command that removes anything but the newest 10 directories within a folder.

```
#! /bin/zsh
cd /path/to/backups/pod1 && rm -rf ./*(Om[1,-11])
```

However, this is limited to just the pod1 directory. I have many backup directories at the same level, i.e. pod1, pod2, pod3 etc... Ideally I'd like to have a wildcard like this:

```
cd /path/to/backups/* && rm -rf ./*(Om[1,-11])
```

...which would do the glob command within any sub directory of backups as per the above.

However, when I run that, I get this message:

```
cd: too many arguments
```

So I am not quite sure how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cd` only takes one argument. One approach is instead to `cd` into each directory (with a sub-shell though that's not necessary *provided* that the directories are all fully qualified (that is to say, the directories are not relative))

```
for d in /path/to/backups/*; do
  ( cd $d && rm -rf ./*(om[1,-11]) )
done
```

Another approach is to just delete the files directly (here with a debugging `print` to confirm first that the correct files have been matched) as multiple globs can be specified in an expression. Note that this keeps 10 files total, whereas the loop-based solution keeps 10 files in each directory.

```
print -l /path/to/backups/pod*/*(Om[1,-11])
```

This however may run into shell limits should too many files be matched, in which case `xargs` or the ZSH `zargs` might be needed.

Comment: The second one isn't doing _anything but the newest 10_ per directory but rather globally... I'd simply run `for d (/path/to/backups/*(/)) print -rl $d/*(Om[1,-11])` here...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help, but -
since the question is a bit old - hope this can at least provide some help to the future readers:

This command finds(*the name of the actual command is find*) every file with the *wildcard [dot]extension at the end of it.

```
find . -name <*.Extension> -type f -exec < command > {} \;
```

where:

- `.` or  - `./` is marking the current directory, use something like  `/home/you/Folders/Files/` to process the **given command** at only files under the Files/ folder. With, the <**Wildcard.Extension**>.
- **<*.Extension>** is the file wildcard-extension e.g `*.dll` or `*.doc`
- `<command>` is the command to execute on all of the found files, e.g `md5sum` to calculate the md5 checksum on every file with the specified .Extension.

### Example 1:

#### execute `head -n 50` command with `| sha256sum` on every file ending with a

`.F0` extension, and save the output in file `Result.out`:

`find . -name *.F0 -type f -exec head -n 50 {} \; | sha256sum >> Result.out`

### Example 2:

#### Same as above, but using environment variables:

```
EXT="*.F0"

CMD="head -n 50"

find . -name $EXT -type f -exec $CMD {} \; | sha256sum >> Result.out
```